# Не работает checkbox в DataGridView

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

На грид добавлена колонка с типом чекбокс. 
Все выводится замечательно, но при нажатии на чекбокс он не отмечается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
dg_drive.DataSource = core.GetListDriver(pid);
dg_drive.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dg_drive.RowHeadersVisible = false;

DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
cb.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
cb.ToolTipText = "Выбрать водителя";
cb.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
cb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
cb.DataPropertyName = "sel_driver";    

dg_drive.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
dg_drive.Columns["fio"].HeaderText = "ФИО Водителя";
dg_drive.Columns["truck_name"].HeaderText = "Траснспорт";
dg_drive.Columns["truck_num"].HeaderText = "Гос.номер";
dg_drive.Columns["trailer_num"].HeaderText = "П/п гос.номер";
dg_drive.Columns.Add(cb);

dg_drive.Columns[6].Width = 30;
dg_drive.Columns[6].DisplayIndex = 0;
dg_drive.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 1;
dg_drive.Columns[2].DisplayIndex = 2;
dg_drive.Columns[3].DisplayIndex = 3;
dg_drive.Columns[4].DisplayIndex = 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя наверное запрещено редактирование DataGridView в целом. Добавь

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = !(bool)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        }
```

проблемка должна уйти